# UseEffect and useState problem with filter (posisible render loop)

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I'm making a small code and my code was working before. I'm trying to separate my functions from my views, but when I do it, there's something that escapes me and I can't find the solution.

This is my old code:

views/letter.js:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

import {
  CButton,
  CCol,
  CRow,
  CImage,
  CContainer,
  CTableRow,
  CTableHead,
  CTableBody,
  CTable,
  CTableHeaderCell,
  CTableDataCell,
  CModal,
  CModalHeader,
  CFormLabel,
  CModalTitle,
  CModalBody,
  CForm,
  CFormInput,
  CFormSelect,
  CNav,
  CNavItem,
  CNavLink,
  CTabPane,
  CTabContent,
} from '@coreui/react'

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MultiSelect } from 'react-multi-select-component';
import axios from "axios";

const options = [
  { label: "Pescado", value: "pescado" },
  { label: "Frutos secos", value: "frutosSecos" },
  { label: "Lacteos", value: "lacteos" },
  { label: "Moluscos", value: "moluscos" },
  { label: "Cereales con gluten", value: "gluten" },
  { label: "Crustáceos", value: "crustaceos" },
  { label: "Huevos", value: "huevos" },
  { label: "Cacahuetes", value: "cacahuetes" },
  { label: "Soja", value: "soja" },
  { label: "Apio", value: "apio" },
  { label: "Mostaza", value: "mostaza" },
  { label: "Sésamo", value: "sesamo" },
  { label: "Altramuces", value: "altramuces" },
  { label: "Sulfitos", value: "sulfitos" },
  { label: "Ninguno", value: "ninguno" },
];


const Carta = () => {
  
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
  const [sections, setSections] = useState([]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState(1)
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
  const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false)
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("");
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState('');
  const [visibleModify, setVisibleModify] = useState(false)
  
  useEffect(() => {
      getProducts();
      getSections();
  }, []);


  const getProducts = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('http://192.168.1.50:9000/getProducts', {
    });
    setProducts(response.data);
    console.log(response.data)
  }

  const getProduct = async (productID) => {
    const response = await axios.post('http://192.168.1.50:9000/getProduct', {
      id: productID,
    });
    setProduct(response.data);
    console.log(response.data)
  }

  const getSections = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('http://192.168.1.50:9000/getSections', {
    });
    setSections(response.data);
    console.log(response.data)
  }

  const saveFile = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    setFileName(e.target.files[0].name);
  };  

  function handlerButton(productID) {
    setVisibleModify(!visibleModify);
    getProduct(productID);
  }

  const deleteProduct = async (e) => {
    try {
      await axios.post('http://192.168.1.50:9000/deleteProduct', {
        id: e.currentTarget.id,
      });
      window.location.reload();
  } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
          setMsg(error.response.data.msg);
      }
  }
  }

  const modifyProduct = async (e, productID) => {
    const form = e.currentTarget

    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      e.preventDefault()
      e.stopPropagation()
    }
    setValidated(true)

    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    formData.append("fileName", fileName);
    console.log(formData.get("fileName"))

    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        "http://192.168.1.50:9000/uploadImg",
        formData
      );
      console.log(res);
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    }

    try {
      await axios.post('http://192.168.1.50:9000/modifyProduct', {
          id: productID,
          name: productName.value,
          description: descp.value,
          price: price.value,
          allergens: JSON.stringify(selected),
          img:formData.get("fileName"),
          section: section.value
      });
      window.location.reload();
  } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
          setMsg(error.response.data.msg);
      }
  }
  }

  const addProduct = async (e) => {
    const form = e.currentTarget

    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      e.preventDefault()
      e.stopPropagation()
    }
    setValidated(true)

    e.preventDefault();


    //////////////
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    formData.append("fileName", fileName);
    console.log(formData.get("fileName"))
    //////////////

    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        "http://192.168.1.50:9000/uploadImg",
        formData
      );
      console.log(res);
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    }



    try {
        await axios.post('http://192.168.1.50:9000/addProduct', {
          name: productName.value,
          description: descp.value,
          price: price.value,
          allergens: JSON.stringify(selected),
          img:formData.get("fileName"),
          section: section.value
        });
        window.location.reload();
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            setMsg(error.response.data.msg);
        }
    }
}


  return (
    <>
    <CContainer >
        <CNav className="justify-content-center mb-4">
          {sections.map((section,index) => {
          return (
          <CNavItem key={index}>
            <CNavLink style={{color: "black"}}
            href="javascript:void(0);"
            active={activeKey === section.id}
            onClick={() => setActiveKey(section.id)}>
              {section.name}
            </CNavLink>
          </CNavItem>
          )})}
        </CNav>
        <CTabContent>
        
        {sections.map((section,index) => {
          return (
            
            <CTabPane key={section.id} role="tabpanel" visible={activeKey === section.id}>
              <CRow>
          <CContainer fluid>
        <CTable>
              <CTableHead>
                <CTableRow>
                  <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Producto</CTableHeaderCell>
                  <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Descripción</CTableHeaderCell>
                  <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Precio</CTableHeaderCell>
                  <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Alergenos</CTableHeaderCell>
                  <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Foto</CTableHeaderCell>
                  <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Acciones</CTableHeaderCell>
                </CTableRow>
              </CTableHead>
              <CTableBody>
              {products.filter(product => product.section == section.id).map((product,index) => {
                var allergens = JSON.parse(product.allergens)
                return (
                  <CTableRow key={product.id}>
                    <CTableDataCell>{product.name}</CTableDataCell>
                    <CTableDataCell>{product.description}</CTableDataCell>
                    <CTableDataCell>{product.price} €</CTableDataCell>
                    <CTableDataCell> 
                      {
                        <div>
                          {allergens.map(p => {
                            return p.label + "  "; 
                          })
                          }
                          </div>                    
                      }
                    </CTableDataCell>
                    <CTableDataCell> 
                      <CImage fluid className="clearfix" src={"http://192.168.1.50:9000/public/images/" + product.img} width={200} height={200}/>
                    </CTableDataCell>
                    <CTableDataCell>
                      <CButton id={product.id} style={{backgroundColor: "#3a8cbe", borderColor: "#3a8cbe"}} onClick={() => handlerButton(product.id)}>Editar</CButton>
                      <p></p>
                      <CButton id={product.id} style={{backgroundColor: "#e8463a", borderColor: "#e8463a"}} onClick={deleteProduct}>Eliminar</CButton>
                    </CTableDataCell>
                  </CTableRow>
                )
            })}
            </CTableBody>
          </CTable>
          </CContainer>
          </CRow>
            </CTabPane>
            
          )})}
          
    </CTabContent>
        <CRow>
          <CContainer fluid>
          <CButton className="mb-4 d-grid mx-auto" color="secondary" style={{color:"white"}} onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}>Añadir producto</CButton>
          <CModal alignment="center" visible={visible} onClose={() => setVisible(false)}>
            <CModalHeader onClose={() => setVisible(false)}>
              <CModalTitle>Añadir producto</CModalTitle>
            </CModalHeader>
            <CModalBody>
            <CForm className="mb-4"
                  validated={validated}
                  onSubmit={addProduct}>
                  <CRow className="mb-3">
                    <CFormLabel htmlFor="colFormLabel" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nombre</CFormLabel>
                    <CCol sm={10} >
                      <CFormInput type="text" id="productName" placeholder="Nombre del producto" pattern="^[a-zA-Z ()]*$"  title="Solo puedes introducir letras a-Z, parentesis o espacios" required/>
                    </CCol>
                  </CRow>
                  <CRow className="mb-3">
                    <CFormLabel htmlFor="colFormLabel" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Descp.</CFormLabel>
                    <CCol sm={10} >
                      <CFormInput type="text" id="descp" placeholder="Descripción"/>
                    </CCol>
                  </CRow>
                  <CRow className="mb-3">
                    <CFormLabel htmlFor="colFormLabel" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Precio</CFormLabel>
                    <CCol sm={10} >
                      <CFormInput type="text" id="price" placeholder="Precio" pattern="[+-]?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?" required/>
                    </CCol>
                  </CRow>
                  <CRow className="mb-3">
                    <CFormLabel htmlFor="colFormLabel" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Alergenos</CFormLabel>
                    <CCol sm={10} >
                      <MultiSelect
                        options={options}
                        value={selected}
                        onChange={setSelected}
                        labelledBy="Seleccione los alergenos"
                      />
                    </CCol>
                  </CRow>
                  <CRow className="mb-3">
                  <CFormLabel htmlFor="colFormLabel" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Sección</CFormLabel>
                    <CCol sm={10} >
                      <CFormSelect id="section" required>
                        <option>Escoja una sección</option>
                        {sections.map((section,index) => {
                        return (
                          <>
                          <option>{section.name}</option>
                          </>
                        )})}
                      </CFormSelect> 
                    </CCol>
                  </CRow>
                  <CRow className="mb-3">
                    <CFormLabel htmlFor="colFormLabel" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Foto</CFormLabel>
                    <CCol sm={10} >
                    <CFormInput type="file" onChange={saveFile} enctype="multipart/form-data" required/>
                    </CCol>
                  </CRow>
                  <CButton className='className="mb-4 d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto' type="submit" color="secondary" style={{color:"white"}}>Añadir</CButton>
            </CForm>
            </CModalBody>
          
          </CModal>
          <CModal alignment="center" visible={visibleModify} onClose={() => setVisibleModify(false)}>
            <CModalHeader onClose={() => setVisibleModify(false)}>
              <CModalTitle>Modificar producto</CModalTitle>
            </CModalHeader>
            <CModalBody>
            <CForm className="mb-4"
                  validated={validated}
                  onSubmit={(e) => modifyProduct(e,product.id)}>
                  <CRow className="mb-3">
                    <CFormLabel htmlFor="colFormLabel" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nombre</CFormLabel>
                    <CCol sm={10} >
                      <CFormInput type="text" id="productName" defaultValue={product.name} pattern="^[a-zA-Z ()]*$"  title="Solo puedes introducir letras a-Z, parentesis o espacios" required/>
                    </CCol>
                  </CRow>
                  <CRow className="mb-3">
                    <CFormLabel htmlFor="colFormLabel" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Descp.</CFormLabel>
                    <CCol sm={10} >
                      <CFormInput type="text" id="descp" defaultValue={product.description}/>
                    </CCol>
                  </CRow>
                  <CRow className="mb-3">
                    <CFormLabel htmlFor="colFormLabel" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Precio</CFormLabel>
                    <CCol sm={10} >
                      <CFormInput type="text" id="price" defaultValue={product.price} pattern="[+-]?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?" required/>
                    </CCol>
                  </CRow>
                  <CRow className="mb-3">
                    <CFormLabel htmlFor="colFormLabel" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Alergenos</CFormLabel>
                    <CCol sm={10} >
                      <MultiSelect
                        options={options}
                        value={selected}
                        onChange={setSelected}
                        labelledBy="Seleccione los alergenos"
                      />
                    </CCol>
                  </CRow>
                  <CRow className="mb-3">
                  <CFormLabel htmlFor="colFormLabel" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Sección</CFormLabel>
                    <CCol sm={10} >
                      <CFormSelect id="section" required>
                      <option>Escoja una sección</option>
                      {sections.map((section,index) => {
                        return (
                          <>
                          <option>{section.name}</option>
                          </>
                        )})}
                      </CFormSelect> 
                    </CCol>
                  </CRow>
                  <CRow className="mb-3">
                    <CFormLabel htmlFor="colFormLabel" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Foto</CFormLabel>
                    <CCol sm={10} >
                    <CFormInput type="file" onChange={saveFile} enctype="multipart/form-data" required/>
                    </CCol>
                  </CRow>
                  <CButton className='className="mb-4 d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto' type="submit" color="secondary" style={{color:"white"}}>Modificar</CButton>
            </CForm>
            </CModalBody>
          </CModal>
          </CContainer>
        </CRow>
    </CContainer>
    </>
  )
}

export default Carta
```

Inside the view I use a function to call the backend to retrieve an array of products. This way it always worked and retrieved the products.

Now what I want to do is to separate the code of those functions to a different .js file but I can't get the setState to work, because it gives me a problem in the filter.

And here is the new code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

import {
  CButton,
  CCol,
  CRow,
  CImage,
  CContainer,
  CTableRow,
  CTableHead,
  CTableBody,
  CTable,
  CTableHeaderCell,
  CTableDataCell,
  CModal,
  CModalHeader,
  CFormLabel,
  CModalTitle,
  CModalBody,
  CForm,
  CFormInput,
  CFormSelect,
  CNav,
  CNavItem,
  CNavLink,
  CTabPane,
  CTabContent,
} from '@coreui/react'

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MultiSelect } from 'react-multi-select-component';
import axios from "axios";
import {getProducts} from "../../services/Product.js"

const options = [
  { label: "Pescado", value: "pescado" },
  { label: "Frutos secos", value: "frutosSecos" },
  { label: "Lacteos", value: "lacteos" },
  { label: "Moluscos", value: "moluscos" },
  { label: "Cereales con gluten", value: "gluten" },
  { label: "Crustáceos", value: "crustaceos" },
  { label: "Huevos", value: "huevos" },
  { label: "Cacahuetes", value: "cacahuetes" },
  { label: "Soja", value: "soja" },
  { label: "Apio", value: "apio" },
  { label: "Mostaza", value: "mostaza" },
  { label: "Sésamo", value: "sesamo" },
  { label: "Altramuces", value: "altramuces" },
  { label: "Sulfitos", value: "sulfitos" },
  { label: "Ninguno", value: "ninguno" },
];


const Carta = () => {
  
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
  const [sections, setSections] = useState([]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const [activeKey, setActiveKey] = useState(1)
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
  const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false)
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("");
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState('');
  const [visibleModify, setVisibleModify] = useState(false)
  
  useEffect(() => {
      setProducts(getProducts());
      getSections();
  }, []);


/*   const getProducts = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('http://192.168.1.50:9000/getProducts', {
    });
    setProducts(response.data);
    console.log(response.data)
  } */
   //setProducts(getProducts());
   console.log(products)

  const getProduct = async (productID) => {
    const response = await axios.post('http://192.168.1.50:9000/getProduct', {
      id: productID,
    });
    setProduct(response.data);
    console.log(response.data)
  }

  const getSections = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('http://192.168.1.50:9000/getSections', {
    });
    setSections(response.data);
    console.log(response.data)
  }

  const saveFile = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    setFileName(e.target.files[0].name);
  };  

  function handlerButton(productID) {
    setVisibleModify(!visibleModify);
    getProduct(productID);
  }

  const deleteProduct = async (e) => {
    try {
      await axios.post('http://192.168.1.50:9000/deleteProduct', {
        id: e.currentTarget.id,
      });
      window.location.reload();
  } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
          setMsg(error.response.data.msg);
      }
  }
  }

  const modifyProduct = async (e, productID) => {
    const form = e.currentTarget

    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      e.preventDefault()
      e.stopPropagation()
    }
    setValidated(true)

    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    formData.append("fileName", fileName);
    console.log(formData.get("fileName"))

    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        "http://192.168.1.50:9000/uploadImg",
        formData
      );
      console.log(res);
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    }

    try {
      await axios.post('http://192.168.1.50:9000/modifyProduct', {
          id: productID,
          name: productName.value,
          description: descp.value,
          price: price.value,
          allergens: JSON.stringify(selected),
          img:formData.get("fileName"),
          section: section.value
      });
      window.location.reload();
  } catch (error) {
      if (error.response) {
          setMsg(error.response.data.msg);
      }
  }
  }

  const addProduct = async (e) => {
    const form = e.currentTarget

    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      e.preventDefault()
      e.stopPropagation()
    }
    setValidated(true)

    e.preventDefault();


    //////////////
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    formData.append("fileName", fileName);
    console.log(formData.get("fileName"))
    //////////////

    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        "http://192.168.1.50:9000/uploadImg",
        formData
      );
      console.log(res);
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    }



    try {
        await axios.post('http://192.168.1.50:9000/addProduct', {
          name: productName.value,
          description: descp.value,
          price: price.value,
          allergens: JSON.stringify(selected),
          img:formData.get("fileName"),
          section: section.value
        });
        window.location.reload();
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            setMsg(error.response.data.msg);
        }
    }
}


  return (
    <>
    <CContainer >
        <CNav className="justify-content-center mb-4">
          {sections.map((section,index) => {
          return (
          <CNavItem key={index}>
            <CNavLink style={{color: "black"}}
            href="javascript:void(0);"
            active={activeKey === section.id}
            onClick={() => setActiveKey(section.id)}>
              {section.name}
            </CNavLink>
          </CNavItem>
          )})}
        </CNav>
        <CTabContent>
        
        {sections.map((section,index) => {
          return (
            
            <CTabPane key={section.id} role="tabpanel" visible={activeKey === section.id}>
              <CRow>
          <CContainer fluid>
        <CTable>
              <CTableHead>
                <CTableRow>
                  <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Producto</CTableHeaderCell>
                  <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Descripción</CTableHeaderCell>
                  <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Precio</CTableHeaderCell>
                  <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Alergenos</CTableHeaderCell>
                  <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Foto</CTableHeaderCell>
                  <CTableHeaderCell scope="col">Acciones</CTableHeaderCell>
                </CTableRow>
              </CTableHead>
              <CTableBody>
              {products.filter(product => product.section == section.id).map((product,index) => {
                var allergens = JSON.parse(product.allergens)
                return (
                  <CTableRow key={product.id}>
                    <CTableDataCell>{product.name}</CTableDataCell>
                    <CTableDataCell>{product.description}</CTableDataCell>
                    <CTableDataCell>{product.price} €</CTableDataCell>
                    <CTableDataCell> 
                      {
                        <div>
                          {allergens.map(p => {
                            return p.label + "  "; 
                          })
                          }
                          </div>                    
                      }
                    </CTableDataCell>
                    <CTableDataCell> 
                      <CImage fluid className="clearfix" src={"http://192.168.1.50:9000/public/images/" + product.img} width={200} height={200}/>
                    </CTableDataCell>
                    <CTableDataCell>
                      <CButton id={product.id} style={{backgroundColor: "#3a8cbe", borderColor: "#3a8cbe"}} onClick={() => handlerButton(product.id)}>Editar</CButton>
                      <p></p>
                      <CButton id={product.id} style={{backgroundColor: "#e8463a", borderColor: "#e8463a"}} onClick={deleteProduct}>Eliminar</CButton>
                    </CTableDataCell>
                  </CTableRow>
                )
            })}
            </CTableBody>
          </CTable>
          </CContainer>
          </CRow>
            </CTabPane>
            
          )})}
          
    </CTabContent>
        <CRow>
          <CContainer fluid>
          <CButton className="mb-4 d-grid mx-auto" color="secondary" style={{color:"white"}} onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}>Añadir producto</CButton
          </CContainer>
        </CRow>
    </CContainer>
    </>
  )
}

export default Carta
```

The problem is with this useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
      setProducts(getProducts());
      getSections();
  }, []);
```

Here is the console:
https://ibb.co/DpK9dCg

Comment: What JSON data does `http://192.168.1.50:9000/getProducts` respond with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is pretty obvious:

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setProducts(getProducts()); // <- new state is undefined
  getSections();
}, []);

const getProducts = async () => { // <- it doesn't return anything
  const response = await axios.get('http://192.168.1.50:9000/getProducts', {
  });
  setProducts(response.data);
  console.log(response.data)
}
```

By doing `setProducts(getProducts())`, your `products` state is now `undefined`, therefore the error message: `products.filter is not a function`.

#### Instead

When moving data fetching functions to a stand alone file, you can pass in the setter function like this:

```
// fileOne.js:
export const getProducts = async (setProducts) => {  // <- set up a setter param
  const response = await axios.get('http://192.168.1.50:9000/getProducts', {
  });
  setProducts(response.data);
  console.log(response.data)
}

// fileTwo.jsx:
import {getProducts} from "fileOne"

const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  getProducts(setProducts); // <- pass in setter function
  getSections();
}, []);
```

This way, your code will work just like your original code.
Please note that, in javascript, function is an object as well, so you can pass it in.

[See sandbox for simple demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-dijkstra-wxnbck)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are setting promise to state. Get products is an async function, so you should write something like:

```
const product = await getProducts()
setProducts(products)
```